# Fetching data from MongoDB and displaying it in React App

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, mern

I am working on creating a web app of an interactive map of campus for the school I'm attending. The web-app will allow students to click on a specific building on campus, which will bring up a map of the classrooms in that building. From there, a user can then click on a classroom which will then display a list of all classes in that room for each day of the school week. I have created my own database of all the classes offered at my school with attributes such as name, section, building, roomnum, and coursenum. I have done enough of the backend where I can connect to my database using Insonmia/Postman where I am able to filter classes based on building, room number and course section (Accounting, Biology etc.) The problem that I am running into is actually displaying the data from my database on the frontend part of my application.

Here is the backend section of my application so far...

**server.js**

```
import express from "express"
import cors from "cors"
import classes from "./api/classes.route.js"

const app = express()

app.use(cors())
app.use(express.json())

app.use("/api/v1/classes", classes)
app.use("*", (req, res) => res.status(404).json({ error: "not found"}))

export default app
```

**index.js**

```
import app from "./server.js"
import mongodb from "mongodb"
import dotenv from "dotenv"
import ClassesDAO from "./dao/ClassesDAO.js"

dotenv.config()
const MongoClient = mongodb.MongoClient

const port = process.env.PORT || 8000

MongoClient.connect(
  process.env.UJCLASSES_DB_URI,
  {
    maxPoolSize: 50,
    wtimeoutMS: 2500,
    useNewUrlParser: true }
  )
  .catch(err => {
    console.error(err.stack)
    process.exit(1)
  })
  .then(async client => {
    await ClassesDAO.injectDB(client)
    app.listen(port, () => {
      console.log(`listening on port ${port}`)
    })
  })
```

**classesDAO.js**

```
import mongodb from "mongodb"
const ObjectId = mongodb.ObjectID
let classes

export default class ClassesDAO {
  static async injectDB(conn) {
    if (classes) {
      return
    }
    try {
      classes = await conn.db(process.env.UJCLASSES_NS).collection("Classes")
    } catch (e) {
      console.error(
        `Unable to establish a collection handle in ClassesDAO: ${e}`,
      )
    }
  }

  static async getClasses({
    filters = null,
    page = 0,
    classesPerPage = 20,
  } = {}) {
    let query
    if (filters) {
      if ("name" in filters) {
        query = { $text: { $search: filters["name"] } }
      } else if ("section" in filters) {
        query = { "section": { $eq: filters["section"] } }
      } else if ("course" in filters) {
        query = { "course": { $eq: filters["course"] } }
      } else if ("room" in filters) {
        query = {"room": { $eq: filters["room"] } }
      }
    }

    let cursor
    
    try {
      cursor = await classes
        .find(query)
    } catch (e) {
      console.error(`Unable to issue find command, ${e}`)
      return { classesList: [], totalNumClasses: 0 }
    }

    const displayCursor = cursor.limit(classesPerPage).skip(classesPerPage * page)

    try {
      const classesList = await displayCursor.toArray()
      const totalNumClasses = await classes.countDocuments(query)

      return { classesList, totalNumClasses }
    } catch (e) {
      console.error(
        `Unable to convert cursor to array or problem counting documents, ${e}`,
      )
      return { classesList: [], totalNumClasses: 0 }
    }
  }
  
  static async getSections() {
    let sections = []
    try {
      sections = await classes.distinct("section")
      return sections
    } catch (e) {
      console.error(`Unable to get sections, ${e}`)
      return sections
    }
  }

  static async getBuildings() {
    let buildings = []
    try {
      buildings = await classes.distinct("building")
      return buildings
    } catch (e) {
      console.error('Unable to get buildings, ${e}')
      return buildings
    }
  }

  static async getRooms() {
    let rooms = []
    try {
      rooms = await classes.distinct("room")
      return rooms
    } catch (e) {
      console.error('Unable to get rooms, ${e}')
      return rooms
    }
  }
}
```

**classes.controller.js**

```
import ClassesDAO from "../dao/ClassesDAO.js"

export default class ClassesController {
  static async apiGetClasses(req, res, next) {
    const classesPerPage = req.query.classesPerPage ? parseInt(req.query.classesPerPage, 10) : 20
    const page = req.query.page ? parseInt(req.query.page, 10) : 0

    let filters = {}
    if (req.query.section) {
      filters.section = req.query.section
    } else if (req.query.course) {
      filters.course = req.query.course
    } else if (req.query.name) {
      filters.name = req.query.name
    } else if (req.query.building) {
      filters.name = req.query.building
    } else if (req.query.room) {
      filters.room = req.query.room
    }

    const { classesList, totalNumClasses } = await ClassesDAO.getClasses({
      filters,
      page,
      classesPerPage,
    })

    let response = {
      classes: classesList,
      page: page,
      filters: filters,
      entries_per_page: classesPerPage,
      total_results: totalNumClasses,
    }
    res.json(response)
  }
  
  static async apiGetClassSections(req, res, next) {
    try {
      let section = await ClassesDAO.getSections()
      res.json(section)
    } catch (e) {
      console.log(`api, ${e}`)
      res.status(500).json({ error: e })
    }
  }

  static async apiGetClassBuildings(req, res, next) {
    try {
      let building = await ClassesDAO.getBuildings()
      res.json(building)
    } catch (e) {
      console.log('api, ${e}')
      res.status(500).json({ error: e })
    }
  }

  static async apiGetClassRooms(req, res, next) {
    try{
      let room = await ClassesDAO.getRooms()
      res.json(room)
    } catch (e) {
      console.log('api, ${e}')
      res.status(500).json({ error: e })
    }
  }
}
```

**classes.route.js**

```
import express from "express"
import ClassesCtrl from "./classes.controller.js"

const router = express.Router()

router.route("/").get(ClassesCtrl.apiGetClasses)
router.route("/sections").get(ClassesCtrl.apiGetClassSections)
router.route("/buildings").get(ClassesCtrl.apiGetClassBuildings)
router.route("/rooms").get(ClassesCtrl.apiGetClassRooms)

export default router
```

I understand that this is not a platform that spits out exact answers, however that is not what I'm looking for. I have been stuck on this problem for over a week and have noticed that my project seems to be different than others. For my project, all I need to do is fetch data from an already completed database and display it. I do not need update, delete or insert functionality.

If anyone could point me in the right direction, or link any docs that could help me out I would be very grateful.

Comment: were you able to fetch the data using Insomnia/Postman?

Comment: Insomnia only allows GET requests, but I believe it is the same as fetch. through insomnia, I am able to pull a list of all items in the collection, as well as pull a list of items in the collection from a specific building/specific room/specific section.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: @NoahMatsubara, Insomnia allows us to use all HTTP Methods such as GET, POST, PUT, etc.. But yes, GET is the same as fetch. Read more about that here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods

Comment: @NoahMatsubara, since you were able to use the GET method to fetch the data, what you will need to do is using a HTTP Client Library, like Axios, that will allow you to fetch the data from the backend